# Is the partition key required when retrieving by the document ID

Tags: partitioning, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to retrieve a document by its ID without specifying the partition key?

My understanding from reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data) is that the query will fan out across all partitions when the partition key is not specified:

> The following query does not have a filter on the partition key
>   (DeviceId) and is fanned out to all partitions where it is executed
>   against the partition's index. Note that **you have to specify the
>   EnableCrossPartitionQuery (x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition
>   in the REST API) to have the SDK to execute a query across partitions**.

This makes sense with non-key properties, but given the ID is treated specially, I'm hoping I won't need to enable cross partition queries for it.

If I do need to enable cross partition queries, would this be an expensive operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query by just ID will be a cross partition operation. You should include the partition key in these queries in `FeedOptions.PartitionKey`, or as part of the filter.
In DocumentDB, ID is **not** unique across all documents within a collection. Instead, the combination of "partition key" and "id" is the primary key and uniquely identifies documents within a collection.

Some applications encode partition key as part of the ID, e.g. partition key would be customer ID, and ID = `"customer_id.order_id"`, so you can extract the partition key from the ID value.

Comment: Thanks Aravind. I might need to rethink my ID strategy. Out of curiosity, is a cross partition query based on the document ID considered to be an expensive (in terms of RUs) operation?

Comment: Please feel free to email askdocdb@microsoft.com in case you'd like to discuss more. Yes, cross partition query by Id is relatively expensive.

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR.: Is the encoding of the partition key as a part of the ID a recommended pattern? Please share your thoughts on this as an answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516506/add-partitionkey-to-child-document-id) if you have the time. Cheers

Comment: What if I don't know the partition key value and only have the document id? Can I still use ReadDocumentAsync in that scenario?