# Encode PartitionKey into Document Id?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, database-partitioning

I have set the partition key of one of my Cosmos DBs to `/partition`.

For example: We have a `Chat` document that contains a list of *Subscribers*, then we have `ChatMessages` that contain a text, a reference to the author and some other properties. Both documents have a `partition` property that contains the type 'chat' and the chats id.

**Chat** example:

```
{
"id" : "955f3eca-d28d-4f83-976a-f5ff26d0cf2c",
"name" : "SO questions",
"isChat" : true,
"partition" : "chat_955f3eca-d28d-4f83-976a-f5ff26d0cf2c",
"subscribers" : [
    ...
]
}
```

We then have **Message** documents like this:

```
{
"id" : "4d1c7b8c-bf89-47e0-83e1-a8cf0d71ce5a",
"authorId" : "some guid",
"isMessage" : true,
"partition" : "chat_955f3eca-d28d-4f83-976a-f5ff26d0cf2c",
"text" : "What should I do?"
}
```

It is now very convenient to return all messages for a specific chat, I just need to query all documents of the partition `chat_955f3eca-d28d-4f83-976a-f5ff26d0cf2c` with the property `isMessage = true`. All good...

But if I now want to query my db for a specific message by id, I usually just know the id, but not the partition and therefor have to run a *slow* `crosspartition` query. Which then led me to the question if I should not add the partitionKey to the  message id so I can split the id when querying the db for a faster lookup. I saw that the _rid property of a document looks like a combination of the id of a db and the id of the collection and then a document specific id. What I mean by this is (simplified):

```
Chat.Id = "abc"
Chat.Partition = "chat_abc"  //[type]_[chatId]
Message.Id = "chat_abc|123" //[Chat.Partition]|[Message.Id]
Message.Partition = chat_abc //[Chat.Partition]
```

Lets assume that I now want to get the `Message` document by the `id`, I just split the `id` by the `|` symbol and then query the document with the 1st part of the `id` as partition and the full id as the key.

Does that make sense? Are there better ways to do this? Should I just always also pass the `partitionKey` of a document along, not just it's `id`? Should I just use the `_rid` properties instead?

Any experience is highly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I have found the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41652348/2360972):

> Some applications encode partition key as part of the ID, e.g.
>   partition key would be customer ID, and ID = "customer_id.order_id",
>   so you can extract the partition key from the ID value.

I have further asked the cosmos team by email if this is a recommended pattern and post an answer, in case I get any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proposal to extract partition key from id (via a convention like a prefix/delimiter) makes sense. This is common among applications that have a single key and want to refactor it to use Cosmos DB from a different storage system.

If you're building your application from scratch, you should consider wiring the composite key (partition key + item key ("id")) through your API/application.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you know your data (and index) size) will remain within the 10gb limit and you RU/sec limit is ok, then a fixed partition-less collection will bypass this problem. Probably OP has knowlingly made the decision that partitioning is required, but it is an important consideration to note for generalization purposes. If possible, KISS ;)

If partitioning is a must, then AFAIK you cannot avoid `crosspartition` split and its overhead unless you know the partition key.

Imho the OP suggestion of merging the duplicated partition key into id field is a rather ugly solution, because:

1. **Name `id` implies it is unique key**, partition key is not part of it or necessary for this key and its uniqueness. Anyone using this key upstream would incur the forced excess cost of longer key, blocked from using the simpler `Guid` type, etc.
2. It will become a mess should your **partitioning key change** in future.
3. The internal structure of merged `id` **would not be intuitive without documentation** - it's parts are not named and even if they look like to have a pattern new devs would not know for sure without finding external documentation to reliably understand what's going on.
4. Your **data model does not require this** duplication on semantic level, it would be for your application querying comfort and hence such hacks should belong to your application code, not data model. Such leaking concerns should be avoided if possible.
5. Data duplication within document would unnecessarily **increase document size, bandwidth**, etc. (may or may not be notable, depending on scale and usage). in-document duplication is necessary at times, but imho not necessarily in this case.

A better design would be to **ensure the partition key is always present in logic context and could be passed along to lookups**. If you don't have it available, then maybe you should refactor you application code (not data design) to explicitly pass around the `chatId` along with `id` where needed. That is **WITHOUT** merging them together into some opaque string format.

Also, I don't see a good way to use `_rid` for this as if I remember correctly, it did not contain any internal reference to a partition or partition key.

**Disclaimer:** I don't have any access or deep insight into internal CosmosDB index design or `_rid` logic on partitioned collections. I may have misunderstood how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs on the issue. I agree with some of your thoughts, but rely in this case on the expertise of a Cosmos DB engineering team member.

Comment: np. It's a matter of ROI/risks. Refactoring choice may cleaner, but obviously costlier as well for existing applications.